# How to scroll list up and down on mouse event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to scroll list up and down but its not working

JSFiddle : [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8TQ5P/1/)

Here is javascript code :

```
   var total = $('ul.item-list li').length;
   var $totalImgs = $('ul.item-list li');

   var thumbHeight = 0;
    for (x=0; x<total; x++) {
        thumbHeight = thumbHeight + 41;
    };

    $('ul.item-list').css({height: thumbHeight + 'px'});

    $('#Up').hover(function(e){
        $('ul.item-list').stop();
        posTop = -parseInt($('ul.item-list').css("margin-top"))
        speed = (posTop) * 4;
        slideTop = thumbHeight - 50;
        $('ul.item-list').animate({"margin-top": "80px"}, 800)},function(){$('ul.item-list').stop();
    });     

    $('#Down').hover(function(e){
        posTop = parseInt($('ul.item-list').css("margin-top"))
        speed = (thumbHeight + posTop) * 4;
        slideTop = thumbHeight - 50;
        $('ul.item-list').stop();
        $('ul.item-list').animate({"margin-top": -slideTop + "px"}, speed)
        },function(){$('ul.item-list').stop();
    });
```

Comment: What specifically isn't working? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Please make a proper fiddle and post it

Comment: So you need all lists scroll up and down only in light gray section

Comment: scroll list does not main overflow:hidden and scroll to top on hover event of #down div...

Answer (score 0):

- Use this CSS for your div - overflow: scroll;
- Then it will scroll and all the list items will come in your div tag

Comment: i dont want to use scroll bar

Comment: +1 @Sumit, is there any way to do this, need scrolling but not scrollbar. overflow-y:scroll or auto comes with scrollbar

Comment: you can use this. This works fine on chrome but not sure for other browsers. if you set overflow-y:scroll; add -webkit-scrollbar also. No need for javascript #element::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none; 
}